# Howto run async boost function in c++?

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, boost-asio, c++17

Does anyone know how I can run an async function using boost, suppose I want to run the foo and bar function asynchronously? Like asyncio function in python.

Demo code

```
void foo(){ }
void bar(){ }

int main(){ return 0;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)? Or [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)? Can you please elaborate on the problem you have and want to solve?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: like std::async, but i dont want to wait for future

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to run `foo` and `bar` in parallel, you can use `<future>` - no need for Boost:

```
int main()
{
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, &foo);
    bar();
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to wait for future result .

Comment: @user1779646: provide an example of what you want to do then. Why would you call `foo` and not wait for it to finish...?

Comment: they will both continue to produce result for the life time of program, and result will be shared between them.

Comment: @user1779646 It seems like what you want is *threads*. Where the function runs independently from much of the rest of the program.

Comment: then how to share result between them, and both should run at the same speed.

Comment: @user1779646 I suggest learning a bit about this. There's no such thing as "sharing the result" unless you wait for it first (that's a data race) and there's no such thing as "run at the same speed". Either threads run or they don't. OS schedules those.